Lipschitz-Continuity of $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \ x \mapsto \max(\sin(x), 0)$.
The case that $x,y \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) = \sin (x)$ and $\sin y < 0 $ and as such $f(y) = 0$ is the one that I am struggling with. For the other cases, one is able to show that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|$. The issue is for those $x$ that are very close, but not equal, to some integer multiple of $\pi$. How do I best go about looking at those cases, either to prove or disprove the Lipschitz-continuity of $f$.

$|\max {a,0}-\max {b,0}| \le |a-b|$.

$\max\lbrace \sin(x), 0 \rbrace = \tfrac{\sin(x) + \lvert \sin(x) \rvert}{2}$
